# Meaning of MIT license

Tags: licensing, mit-license

Suppose I use this ActionScript API released under MIT license
to build a software: http://www.cove.org/ape/docs/api/

1. Can I sell that software?
2. Do I need to give the source code of my software away?
3. Is anyone receiving my software permitted to resell the software?

Comment: Isnt there a database to register your project to MIT licence? http://opensource.org/licenses/bsd-license.php greetings

Comment: meta discussion about this question: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6861/31260

Comment: Best answer I've found for my purposes: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178486/what-exactly-does-the-condition-in-the-mit-license-imply

Answer (score 174, accepted):

1. You can sell the software.
2. No, you are not compelled to provide source code.
3. Anyone who receives *source code* may do as the license permits. This does not extend to binary distributions.

Read the MIT license. Read the whole thing and understand it. It was meant to be read by ordinary people, unlike other licenses that are very complex:

> Copyright (c) *year* *copyright holders*
>
> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS",
>   WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS
>   OR IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED
>   TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND
>   NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
>   AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE
>   FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
>   LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF
>   CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING
>   FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE
>   SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS
>   IN THE SOFTWARE.

Comment: I agree, read the license, it's short: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html

Comment: Maybe the thing he wanted to ask was weather he can license his product under some commercial license (is MIT license copyleft?)?

Comment: Jox, I pasted the ENTIRE license above so you can see for yourself. BSD/MIT/ISC style licensed software have been included in Mac OS, Windows, etc... You cannot remove the license/copyright, but you can do pretty much anything else. It's not viral.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I've been confused by the MIT license as well. The confusion stems from the fact that the license talks about the 'Software' to which the license applies. So if I link to MIT-licensed 'Software' and distribute a derivative + MIT license (mandatory) then this implies that the derivative would become the 'Software' according to the license. To be clear: there is no mention of source code\binary distribution anywhere, just 'Software'.

Comment: Even as a native speaker, I found it difficult to understand. If the permission notice has to be included in all copies of the software, and if compiled binaries are still "copies of the software", then seemingly the permission notice has to be included with your compiled binaries. If you are including the permission notice, then seemingly you are giving recipients permission to copy "the software" -- i.e. both the MIT-licensed library software and your own software together. I know that this is not the intent of the license ... but still, it is confusing to the literal minded such as myself.

Comment: You ask that people read the license, but nowhere do I see support for your point (3) that the license rights only transitively extend to people receiving source copies of the software, rather than binary copies. In fact, there is no distinction at all between "source" and "binary" at all in the license. Furthermore, _software_ is commonly understood as meaning both the source and binary forms when considering the notice clause, so it be very odd for it to have the opposite meaning elsewhere in the license.

Comment: I agree - advice like "read some legal document" is predicated on the reader having some legalese foundation, which shouldn't be assumed. Here, the paragraph `The above ... shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software` means: this *notice* should simply be included in one's proprietary software, but it doesn't apply to the proprietary software itself. It's like an advertisement to the open source component. Essentially saying "Hey in my closed source commercial software, I used OpenAwesome, which is MIT-licensed (so you can grab a copy of OpenAwesome and use it too)"

Comment: See also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/178493/270224.

Answer (score 24):

According to ["Understanding Open Source and Free Software Licensing" by By Andrew M. St. Laurent](http://oreilly.com/openbook/osfreesoft/book/):

> These licenses, as applied to the original licensed code, allow that code to be used in
>   proprietary software and do not require that open source versions of the code be dis-
>   tributed. Code created under these licenses, or derived from such code, may go
>   “closed” and developments can be made under that proprietary license, which are
>   lost to the open source community. For the same reason, however, these licenses are
>   very flexible and compatible with almost every form of open source license.

Comment: They should really spell out that you can distribute the compiled software without distributing the MIT license, and that you can distribute your own source code that uses the MIT-licensed software, with the MIT license only applying to the MIT-licensed software. i.e.The MIT license just protects the stuff it licenses, and does not make your additional work that works with that code need to be MIT-licensed too. Almost everyone who attempts to explain licenses doesn't go into those points.

Answer (score 19):

As always, consult a lawyer. If this library is released strictly using the MIT license then:

(i) Yes, you can sell your software provided you include the MIT license as part of your product.
(ii) No, you don't have to share your code with the community but it would be nice.
(iii) Yes, reselling is permitted.

MIT License:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of
>   charge, to any person obtaining a copy
>   of this software and associated
>   documentation files (the "Software"),
>   to deal in the Software without
>   restriction, including without
>   limitation the rights to use, copy,
>   modify, merge, publish, distribute,
>   sublicense, and/or sell copies of the
>   Software, and to permit persons to
>   whom the Software is furnished to do
>   so, subject to the following
>   conditions:
>
> The above copyright notice and this
>   permission notice shall be included in
>   all copies or substantial portions of
>   the Software.

Comment: "As always, consult a lawyer." This is extremely impractical advice for a great deal of situations.

Comment: With any sort of commercial business dealing with licensing however it can be a great quote to keep in mind. I don't think he literally means always consult a lawyer

Comment: all copies or substantial portions?

Comment: @Pacerier I think it means *all substantial copies of the Software*. :p